# How to get uid from Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to get UID (user-id) from a logged-in user, but I am getting an error as uid is null:

```html
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  getCurrentUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    // Similarly we can get email as well
    //final uemail = user.email;
    print(uid);
    //print(uemail);
  }
```

and the error is:
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.

Please help me solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing the package that you are using is updated and `FirebaseUser` is now deprecated.As an equivalent use `User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;`

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
print(user.uid);
```

The issue could be you have not logged in correctly.

Comment: i have logged in, and also i am able to get uid in create account page

Comment: but here i am not able to get it

Comment: Okay I got the issue. you are not using the same instance of FirebaseAuth in the pages.Meaning you are initializing one FirebaseAuth in create account page(which is authenticated).Other one at other page which is a different instance and it is not authenticated.Please check and tell me that is the case then i will get the solution

Comment: I am using this method
final newuser =
                          await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);
                      print("newuser");
                      // print(newuser);
                      print(newuser.user.uid);

Comment: in register page

Comment: static FirebaseApp app;
static FirebaseFirestore firestore;
app = await Firebase.initializeApp();
firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: app);
put this is main.dart and check

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not logged in at all.
When not logged in, _auth.currentUser() will return null instead of a User.

Could it be that this is a timing problem and you are calling _auth.currentUser() too early when the login is not finished yet?

Comment: i am able to get uid in create account page

Comment: but here i am not able to get it